# Equivalence of integral

Tags: integration, analysis

Let $1<p<\infty$ and $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function ($\Omega$ is a an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$). Then are the following two integral equalities equivalent:
$$
\int_{\Omega}u\,dx=0
$$
and
$$
\int_{\Omega}|u|^{p-2}u\,dx=0.
$$
I am hopeful; they are not equivalent as in the first one $u+v$ is there if $u,v$ are but in the second not true.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\Omega=(-1,1)$ and $u(x)=-\mathbb{1}_{(-1/2,0]}(x)+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(x)$.

$\int_\Omega u =0$

For $p\neq2$

$\int|u|^{p-2}u =-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^{p-1}}\neq0$

Tweaking this example a little you can also obtain a function $v$ such that $\int|v|^{p-2}v=0$ but $\int v\neq0$.

In general, for any measure space $(\Omega,\mathscr{B}(\Omega),m)$, $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ open, $\mathscr{B}(\Omega)$ Borel sets in $\Omega$,
if $u=u_+-u_-$ where $u_+=\max(0,u)$ and $u_-=-\min(0,u)$
$$\int|u|^{p-2}u\,dm=\int u^{p-1}_+-u^{p-1}_-\,dm$$

From this you can cook up measurable functions such that $\int u\,dm=0$ but $\int|u|^{p-2}u\,dm\neq0$.